# Record Average Consecutive Days by Group

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble with the following columns with over a million rows:

```
   Emp_ID Start_Date Consec_Days
    <int> <date>           <dbl>
 1   4    2018-02-19          NA
 2   4    2018-02-20           1
 3   4    2018-02-21           1
 4   3    2016-12-26          NA
 5   3    2017-01-02           0
 6   3    2017-01-03           1
 7   3    2017-01-04           1
 8   3    2017-01-06           0
 9   3    2017-01-07           1
10   3    2017-01-09           0
```

Start_Date is the day an employee goes to work.  I'd like to create a column that calculates the average number of consecutive days worked for each unique employee  ID.  Each NA value denotes the very first day a particular employee went to work.  The problem is I don't know how to account for the NA values and 0's in the Consec_Days column to get an average of consecutive days.

I've tried referencing the following posts but haven't been able to make it work on my end:

[How to find mean of n consecutive days in each group r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914669/how-to-find-mean-of-n-consecutive-days-in-each-group-r)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please clarify the desired output. E.g. 'Emp_ID' 4 works three consecutive days. This does not agree with the (accepted) answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Emp_ID) %>% 
  mutate(average_cons_days = sum(Consec_Days, na.rm = TRUE)/n())
```

```
   Emp_ID Start_Date Consec_Days average_cons_days
    <int> <chr>            <int>             <dbl>
 1      4 2018-02-19          NA             0.667
 2      4 2018-02-20           1             0.667
 3      4 2018-02-21           1             0.667
 4      3 2016-12-26          NA             0.429
 5      3 2017-01-02           0             0.429
 6      3 2017-01-03           1             0.429
 7      3 2017-01-04           1             0.429
 8      3 2017-01-06           0             0.429
 9      3 2017-01-07           1             0.429
10      3 2017-01-09           0             0.429
```

Comment: Isn't this `mean`

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the `mean:`

```
library(plyr)


df=data.frame("Emp_ID"=c(4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                "Start_Date"=c("2018-02-19","2018-02-20", "2018-02-21", "2016-12-26", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-06", "2017-01-07", "2017-01-09"),
                "Consec_Days"=c(NA,1,1,NA,0,1,1,0,1,0))


df %>%
  group_by(Emp_ID) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(Consec_Days, na.rm=TRUE))

   Mean
1 0.625
```